# Why does Mathematica import data with quotation?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am importing data from `ParallelTable` as `dat` file and then export it again for visualization. However, the exported data contains a quotation  `" "` and can not use `ListPlot`, here is an example

```
Y = ParallelTable[{x}, {x, -20, 20, 2}] // AbsoluteTiming;
Export["...\\Hello3.dat", Y];
data = Import["...\\Hello3.dat"];
```

the imported data has this form

```
{{0.0326645}, {"{-20}", "{-18}", "{-16}", "{-14}", "{-12}", "{-10}", 
  "{-8}", "{-6}", "{-4}", "{-2}", "{0}", "{2}", "{4}", "{6}", "{8}", 
  "{10}", "{12}", "{14}", "{16}", "{18}", "{20}"}}
```

If I use `ListPlot[data[[2]]]` it does not give output. So how can I avoid these quotations from the beginning with keeping `AbsoluteTiming`?

Comment: You should specify the import and export format explicitly.

Comment: @Szabolcs How can I do that?

Comment: Try `Put` and `Get`.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ may you please elaborate?

Comment: I expect it's because `Y` is not an array. Omit `AbsoluteTiming`.

Comment: Hi, I mean, if you are deal with plain-text-wise data (as what I see now), you can use `Put` to store the data and use `Get` to get the data back into kernel.

Comment: `Put[Y, "Hello3.dat"]; Get["Hello3.dat"] // InputForm`. Pay attention that the order of arguments of `Put` is just opposite to that of `Export`.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ, that is completely solved it. Thanks! can you please post it as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Note that `Put` and `Get` are for communicating in WL. See also some of the `*Save` functions

Comment: See the documentation of Import and Export. Import[filename, format] and Export[filename, data, format].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I have not dug very deep in this issue but just post my experience. And not about why but about how to get rid of the quotation marks.

When I deal with plaintext-wise data, I just use `Put` to store the data and later use `Get` to get it back *in the same form as I `Put` it, without the requirement to set up other options*. In your case, this should work:

```
Put[Y, "Hello3.dat"];
data = Get["Hello3.dat"]
```

No directory specified explicitly means that `$UserDocumentsDirectory`(at least in Win 10) is used. You can specify other directory if you prefer.